# Link to relationship post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a WordPress website that has installed Advanced Custom Fields. One of the pages is showing a release by a band. I have created a custom post type for releases and one for lyrics. The release has a flexible content field called `'tracklist'`. This field has a layout called `'tracks'` with a row with two fields called `'trackname'` (text), and `'lyrics'` (relationship). `'lyrics'` has been set to max one post, so you can only choose the lyrics for that specific song.

How am I able to get the link from this relationship field called `'lyrics'`?

Here's the code I have so far, but of course `$lyrics` contains an array, so it won't work:

```
// check if the flexible content field has rows of data
if( have_rows('tracklist') ):

    $x = 1;
    echo '<p class="tracklist">';
     // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('tracklist') ) : the_row();

        if( get_row_layout() == 'tracks' ):
            $trackname = get_sub_field('trackname');
            $lyrics = get_sub_field('lyrics');

            echo '<strong>'.$x.'</strong> '.$trackname.' <a href="'.$lyrics.'">(lyrics)</a><br />';
        endif;
        $x++;

    endwhile;

    echo '</p>';


endif;
```

From the [website](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) of the plugin, I found this code. But is there an easier way as there only are one relationship?

```
<?php 

$posts = get_field('relationship_field_name');

if( $posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $p ): // variable must NOT be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $p->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $p->ID ); ?></a>
            <span>Custom field from $post: <?php the_field('author', $p->ID); ?></span>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```